# Probability of outputs in a ternary communication channel.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In this communication channel there are 3 inputs ( $0,1,2$ ) as you may see in the picture below. Each one of them appear with a probability of $\frac{1}{4}$ ( for $0$ )$, \frac{1}{4} $ ( for $1$ ) $, \frac{1}{2}$ ( for $2$ ) .
 Probability of the corrrect symbol to be recieved is $: p=1-ε$ and probability of a wrong one to be transmitted is : $p'=ε$

> $(a')$ We want to know the probability of each symbol to appear in the output.
>
> $(b')$ If $1$ is the output, what is the probability of : *input is $0$*?

I really can't think of anything to solve this. I searched for other similar posts but there weren't any using ternary channels. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: ternary communication channel]

Comment: Use conditional probability, for example P(output is 0) = P(output is 0 | input is 0)*P(input is 0)+P(output is 0 | input is 1)*P(input is 1)+P(output is 0 | input is 2)*P(input is 2)

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of using condition probability. I think the 2nd one is similar, so I can handle it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you got a good direction in the comments, but just to compare your result. Denote with $Y$ the output and with $X$ the input (ot $O$ and $I$ if your prefer). Then for $(a')$
\begin{align}P(Y_0)&=P(Y_0\mid X_0)P(X_0)+P(Y_0\mid X_1)P(X_1)+P(Y_0\mid X_2)P(X_2)\\[0.2cm]&=(1-\epsilon)\frac14+\epsilon\frac14+0\frac12=\frac14\end{align} and similarly $P(Y_1)=\frac14(1+\epsilon),P(Y=2)=\frac14(2-\epsilon)$. Hence for (b') (by Bayes theorem)
\begin{align}P(X_0\mid Y_1)&=\frac{P(Y_1\mid X_0)P(X_0)}{P(Y_1)}\end{align} but actually here you do not this, because the output $1$ can occur only if the input is $1$ or $2$, so this probability is directly $0$.

Comment: How is the probability of this 0?
\begin{align}P(X_0\mid Y_1)&=\frac{P(Y_1\mid X_0)P(X_0)}{P(Y_1)}\end{align}

Comment: @George.K Because $P(Y_1\mid X_0)=0$. In your diagram if you start from input $0$ you can land only in $0$ or in $2$ not in $1$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am sorry, I got a bit lost. Thanks for your help!